# How would I display data from an array in an object in an array?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display information to the user showing what `communities` they are in, inside of the view. Here is the controller method where I'm getting the data:

```
public function index()
{
    $communities = array();

    $usersCommunities = CommunityMemberList::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    foreach ($usersCommunities as $community) {
        $communitiesInfo = Community::where('id', $community->community_id)->get();

        array_push($communities, $communitiesInfo);
    }

    return view('home', compact('communities', 'badges'));
}
```

`$userCommunities` gets all of the community `ids` that the user has from a table. Then I want to get the all of the communities information from another table using the `community_id`.

So basically there are 2 tables:

- `community_member_list` which has a `community_id` and a `user_id` column
- `communities` which has irrelevant information about a community

The `community_id` from the first table will correspond to the `id` in the second table.

This works, it gets all of the communities information data that the user is in and returns this data after being pushed into the `$communities` array from the `foreach` loop:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Collection {#236 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => Community {#249 ▼
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "communities"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:10 [▶]
        #original: array:10 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: []
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #fillable: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#250 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => Community {#251 ▼
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "communities"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:10 [▶]
        #original: array:10 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: []
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #fillable: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However, if I return this to the view I cannot access the specific data values such as a community `name` or `description`. And if I try using something like `array_pop` or `array_shift`, it only returns either the last community array or the first community array.

(This is the view file for reference:)

```
@if(!empty($communities))
    @foreach($communities as $community)
        <div class="card communityCard bg-dark col-md-3">
            <img class="communityIcon" src="/images/communityIcons/{{$community->icon_path}}">

            <div class="communityInformation">
                <span class="communityTitle">{{$community->name}}</span>
                <span class="userCount"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> {{$community->user_count}}</span>
            </div>

            <button class="btn launchCadBtn btn-primary  btn-sm">Launch CAD</button>
      </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <span class="subTitle">You are not in any Communities. To join a Community, press the <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> button and enter a Community ID</span>
@endif
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You are doing many queries.You can do it with 2 query. Try my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the values as follows in your controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $communities = array();

    $usersCommunities = CommunityMemberList::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    foreach ($usersCommunities as $community) {
        $communitiesInfo = Community::where('id', $community->community_id)->first();

        array_push($communities, $communitiesInfo);
    }

    return view('home', ['communities' => $communities, 'badges' => $badges]);
}
```

And the view should work fine. The problem is that you're trying to access the `$communities` as a collection but it's actually an array of communities, which itself was a collection of collections due to **get()** and badges list.

Comment: Already tried that and it's returning this error from the `foreach` loop in the view; 


`Property [icon_path] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Users/EthanPhelps/Websites/cadispatch/resources/views/home.blade.php)`. 


`icon_path` is a column in the database but because it's nested inside of another object you can't just retrieve it with the foreach loop.

Comment: There is a 'hack' way of making it work, and that's by putting a foreach loop inside of a foreach loop. But this isn't a clean method.

Comment: That is because `$communitiesInfo = Community::where('id', $community->community_id)->get();` returns a collection. So basically `$communities` is a collection of collection, whereas `first()` returns the model. Try my edit.

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression that `first()` would only get 1. But I was mistaken! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution it is only 2 query

```
public function index()
{
    $communitiesIds = CommunityMemberList::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('community_id');
    $communities = Community::whereIn('id', $communitiesIds)->get();

    return view('home', ['communities' => $communities, 'badges' => $badges]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I thought it was a bit overkill :)